# Find the polar coordinates of the midpoint of the line segment joining these points.

Tags: geometry

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two points in the plane whose polar coordinates are
given as $(12, 4π/9)$ and $(12, −2π/9)$ respectively. Find the polar coordinates of the midpoint of the line segment joining these points.

My attempt  :  mid points  will be  = $( \frac{12 +12}{2} ,\frac{ 4\pi/9 -2\pi/9}{2})= (12, \pi /9)$

Is  its  true ??

Comment: Both points are on the circle with radius $12$ centered at the origin. So  is your answer, so it can't possibly be the midpoint. I suggest drawing a picture. Then you may want to convert to rectangular coordinates.

Comment: @EthanBolker..im not  getting    how  its   is a circle ??

Comment: Each of those points has $r=12$ so each is on the circle of radius $12$. Their midpoint must be inside that circle. Draw a picture!

Comment: @EthanBolker. pythagoras  theorem,,,can used or not .??..as i draw the  diagram,,,

Comment: $P_1=(r_1,\theta_1)$ and $P_2=(r_2,\theta_2)$ the polar coordinates then this points can be represented by the vectors $OP_1=r_1e^{\theta_1i}$ and $OP_2=r_2e^{\theta_2i}$ then the midpoint of $P_1P_2$ can be represented by the vector $\frac{1}{2}(OP_1+OP_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Shivering Soldier gives an answer in rectangular coordinates, for the midpoint of a segment whose endpoints are specified in polar coordinates.

In polar coordinates, that midpoint is at

$$\bigg( \frac{ \sqrt {r^{2}+r'^{2} + 2 r r'\cos (\theta -\sigma) }} 2 ,  \arctan \frac{r \sin\theta + r' \sin\sigma }{r \cos\theta + r' \cos\sigma}\bigg) $$

Comment: I apologize. I was reviewing this post and I thought it was somebody trying to ask a question instead of give an answer. Again, I am sorry, I misread the post I was reviewing.

Comment: Using the classic precalculus definition ("principal value", see Wikipedia for example), the range of $\arctan$ is $(-\pi/2.\pi/2)$, so this answer does not apply in all cases. There are other definitions of $\arctan$ (different range, as a multivalued function, etc) but they would also introduce problems